# Vote to undelete question ... and rationale

Tags: discussion, support

I triggerd a vote to undelete a question entitled

> I have used TER to break the long bonds of a chain in my PDB

The question is [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/14887/i-have-used-ter-to-break-the-long-bonds-of-a-chain-in-my-pdb), deleted by the OP after it was answered by a member of the site and appropriate expert here.

I don't understand the question, but it appears to have been well answered.

It is not the first time this has happened, a new OP account deleted a question answered by the responder in very recent history (weeks), in similar circumstances and reported here.

I do feel it is important to protect valid answers and would welcome support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree and have undeleted the question. If someone has provided a reasonable answer to a question then the question may NOT be deleted.

Comment: Many thanks @DevonRyan as a general principle its something I think is important.

Comment: This is a very good question, and inserting TER into PDB files is something which is often needed in the structural bioinformatics world, a world which is largely esoteric and poorly documented versus sequencing bioinformatics. It would be good to encourage structural bioinformatics questions.